# ¿Por qué este código no me da una violación de segmento?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

En este código no tengo un constructor copy, supongo que se hace la copia de las direcciones de los punteros al asignar el objeto 'l' a 'a', si el destructor se ejecuta dos veces, ¿por qué no me da una violación de segmento?:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
    public:
    int value;
    Node* next;
    Node(int value,Node* next)
    :value{value},next{next}
    {}
    ~Node()
    {
    }
};
class LinkedList
{
    private:
    Node* first;
    Node* last;
    public:
    LinkedList():first{nullptr},last{nullptr}{}
    void add(int value)
    {
        Node* item = new Node{value,nullptr};
        if(!first)
        {
            first = last = item;
            return;
        }
        last->next = item;
        last = item;
    }
    void print() const
    {
        auto aux = first;
        while(aux)
        {
            aux = aux->next;
        }
    }
    ~LinkedList()
    {
        cout<<"chau"<<endl;
        while(first)
        {
            delete first;
            first = first->next;
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    LinkedList l;
    l.add(1);
    l.add(22);
    l.add(333);
    l.add(4444);
    l.add(55555);
    l.print();
    LinkedList a = l;
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Llamar 2 veces a `delete` **sobre un mismo puntero** es lo que se conoce como un [*comportamiento indefinido*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).

Tomado del enlace anterior:

> Los efectos de la invocación de una operación que provoque un comportamiento indefinido pueden variar dependiendo de la arquitectura del procesador en la que se ejecute el programa, el cambio en cualquiera de los elementos de la cadena de herramientas (como el compilador), el sistema operativo, el contenido de la memoria, el momento de ejecución, etc.
>   
>   Entre los posibles efectos de la invocación de un comportamiento indefinido está la ejecución esperada del programa (lo que oculta el problema), el cierre inesperado del programa, corrupción de la memoria, resultados incorrectos, fallo irrecuperable del sistema informático, vulnerabilidades de seguridad, etc.

Fíjate que **no** se indica que se **deba** de producir ningún efecto, y mucho menos un efecto *visible*. Es decir, puedes *romper* algo pero no tiene porqué indicarse. En tu caso, lo mas probable es que estés produciendo una *corrupción* en el sistema de memoria ... corrupción que puede no ser visible hasta que tu programa no lleve algún tiempo en ejecución con múltiples llamadas a `new` y `delete`.

Comment: ... también puede pasar que no suceda absolutamente nada ... XD

Comment: También ... raro, pero posible :-). Casi mejor lo dejo sin poner en la respuesta ¿ no crees ? No vayamos dando *ideas raras* al personal ...

Comment: jajajaja. Solo viendo que se trata de un comportamiento indefinido ya es motivo suficiente para no acercarse XD